# Fix Windows 7/8 taskbar's new toolbar size when locked

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

After I added a new toolbar and locked the taskbar, this is what happened:
[image: Screenshot]

There is a bit of an icon in the right part of the toolbar's text. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried unlocking, dragging the toolbar to the left, then resizing the taskbar to its original single row size and re-locking? There are also options to show/hide text and titles if you right-click a toolbar.

Comment: I'm adding a bounty to this because the only answer doesn't work for me. Additionally I can't rig this to work at all in a vertical taskbar orientation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to re-position the toolbars, lock/unlock the taskbar, move the taskbar to the left/right/top/bottom...

The only thing that worked was to "try" to make the taskbar's height smaller (just clicked on it and tried to drag it down) while locked. That fixed my toolbars to display correctly. Strange but true..

Thanks to **Karan** for the ideea. Next time i'll try to enable/disable the toolbar's text/titles and post if it worked or not